# Can the input buffer for pyserial overflow? How can I detect it?

Tags: python, buffer-overflow, pyserial

I have a python script talking to a serial device with `pyserial`, and somewhere along the line a packet is being lost. I suspect there's a serial buffer overflowing somewhere.

How can I detect if the input buffer overflows python-side?